# Changes in font size of textArea gives unexpected results

Tags: codenameone

I have a textArea which occupies whole screen when the font is larger. But with smaller font size, it leaves large space. The textArea has margin , padding zero. The problem is seen in both simulator and real devices (I've checked in android devices).

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new BorderLayout());
hi.show();

TextArea priceLabel = new TextArea("AG and Company works in Nepal for manufacturing, marketing and exporting herbal products and organic argo products. The products include organic coffee, spices, body care products, crude herbs, cosmetic products, and vegetable oil and herbal teas.  The organization is located in Sinamangal, Kathmandu and the chairman is Mr.Sitaram Adhikari.");
priceLabel.setUIID("small");
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setMarginLeft(1);
priceLabel.setEditable(false);
priceLabel.setGrowByContent(true);
priceLabel.setFocusable(false);
priceLabel.setScrollVisible(false);
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setMargin(0,0,0,0);
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setPadding(0,0,0,0);

Container herbDetailContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(new Label(), priceLabel);
herbDetailContainer.setScrollableY(true);
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, herbDetailContainer);
hi.revalidate();
```

font size 1mm (native:MainThin)

[image]

font size 2mm (native:MainThin)

[image]

font size 3mm (native:MainThin)

[image]

font size 4mm (native:MainThin)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
priceLabel.setRows(4); 
priceLabel.setColumns(100);
```

This gives the text area an initial size that makes sense so growth calculations don't go haywire.

I'm guessing you didn't set the font in both selected/unselected.

```
Form hi = new Form("Text Area", BoxLayout.y());

TextArea priceLabel = new TextArea("AG and Company works in Nepal for manufacturing, marketing and exporting herbal products and organic argo products. The products include organic coffee, spices, body care products, crude herbs, cosmetic products, and vegetable oil and herbal teas.  The organization is located in Sinamangal, Kathmandu and the chairman is Mr.Sitaram Adhikari.");
priceLabel.setRows(4);
priceLabel.setColumns(100);
priceLabel.setUIID("Label");
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setFont(
        Font.createTrueTypeFont("native:MainLight", "native:MainLight").
            derive(convertToPixels(1), Font.STYLE_PLAIN));
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setMarginLeft(1);
priceLabel.setEditable(false);
priceLabel.setGrowByContent(true);
priceLabel.setFocusable(false);
priceLabel.setScrollVisible(false);
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setMargin(0,0,0,0);
priceLabel.getAllStyles().setPadding(0,0,0,0);
hi.add(priceLabel);

hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: yeahhh... I have set font using uiid (unselected only). Setting it in all selected and pressed solved the problem. But why should it affect here? The textArea should have taken only unselected style at first, isn't it?

Comment: The preferred size/line break code needs to work for both cases to prevent the component from "jumping around"